# regex does not work with mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, arrays

How can you perform a search and replace with php on an array returned from `mysql_fetch_array()`? If I use `preg_replace()` it will not return a match. Is there something that I'm missing?
This is what I have used without sucess, could anyone pleas take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong, or possibly a better way to achive this:

```
mysql_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD)
    or die("<p>Error connecting to database: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME)
    or die("<p>Error selecting the database " . DATABASE_NAME . mysql_error() . "</p>");
$sql = "SELECT product_id,description FROM oc_product_description WHERE product_id >= 97 AND product_id <= 100";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$pattern = '/^.*\b([0-9]{6}\s\D\d|[0-9]{6}\s\D[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{7}\s\D[0-9]{2})\b.*$/';
$replace = '$1';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    $item[] = $row['description'];
}
foreach($item as $items)
{
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $items) . '<br>'; 
    echo '<br>';
}
```

all that this will do is return the same as it would without the `preg_replace()`. Now I know the code works because if I output a `print_r($item)` and copy the results into an array it works just fine. Am i doing something wrong or does `preg_replace()` just not work with arrays returned from `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_array`? I could put my example up where i copy the results into an array but dont want to waste space. Here is an example of an item returned from the database and the string I'm trying to match with regex. I need everything removed but the match.

One item returned from  $row['description']:

`1997 Suzuki VZ800 Marauder, Engine # 5506-111789, Kick stand and spring. Chrome on end is starting to chip. 0121103 S19 <img src = ">http://www.roofis27.com/motorcycle/13_01_21/103.JPG">`

Here is what the regex retrurns: `0121103 S19`

So therefore I have over 20,000 entry's in a database with descriptions like these and need these codes like the example above removed from them so I can `INSERT` them into another table column that matches the `product_id` relational to the descriptions `product_id`. I am not the best with SQL, but the `<img>` tag is always after the code so maybe there is a way to do it with SQL that I'm not aware of? My main concern at this point is why `preg_replace()` doesn't work with an array returned from `mysql_fetch_array()`, but works fine on any other arrays ( associative, multidimensional or not). Is there something about the values returned from a database that prevent me from being able to do this? Anything would be greatly appreciated, I'm really stuck on this!

Comment: Seriously, is there a rock where 90% of Stack Overflow question askers have been hiding under for the last 5 - 10 years? **Stop using the MySQL extension for new code!** Just stop it! Pretend it doesn't exist. See the big, red warning [here](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php) (and on every other `mysql_*` function)? Read it and take heed

Comment: I don't know what you've tried, but I'd test with a MUCH simpler regular expression in your code. What you describe is consistent with a match not being found. Copy/paste of the string you get out can remove invisible characters at the end of the string, for instance, so your print_r test may not be accurate.

Comment: So what exactly are you seeing from this? Nothing but a bunch of `<br>` pairs?

Comment: thank you jerry, that was all I needed to know, is there a way to filter what is returned from the database? Sorry for using the wrong extension.

Comment: The way you "filter what is returned from the database" is by using the WHERE clause in your SQL statement.

Comment: yes, but that would just filter the whole field so if I did `SELECT description FROM db_product WHERE description REGEXP "[0-9]{6}\s\D\d";` This would not give me the results I'm looking for it would just match the rows that have this in the description. I would like to know a way in MySQL to actually remove that part of the regexp, then I could update another table. php is the only way i know how to do it, If anybody knows a way to achieve what I'm doing below in MySQL I would be very happy to see how this would be done. I will show the complete code below this comment..

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about what jerry had to say(in the comment above) I came up with this resolution, apparently there are characters in the return from `mysql_fetch_array()` that are invisible and that's why the regexp does not work. I got way better results using `preg_match()` as follows:

```
$sql = 'SELECT product_id,description FROM oc_product_description';
$sql1 = 'UPDATE db_product SET model = ';
$sql2 = 'WHERE product_id = ';
$pattern = '([0-9]{6}\s\D[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{6}\s\D\d|[0-9]{7}\s\D[0-9]{2})';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $data[] = $row['description'];
  foreach($data as $datas)
  { 
    preg_match($pattern, $datas, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
  }
  foreach($matches as $match)
  {
    $Q1 = $sql1 . '"'. $match[0] . '"' . ' ';
  }
  $Q2 = $sql2 . $row['product_id'] .';';
  $query = $Q1 . $Q2;
  mysql_query($query);
  echo 'Product ID' . $row['product_id'] . ': ';
  printf("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Yes, I will start using PDO for database cons and querys, did some research on it and look pretty cool. It's just I'm new to php and still in school so I have so much learning going on I hate having to change ( better get used to it though, HUH?) Thank you jerry :)